# How can I repeat the whole code until the user quits?

Tags: c++, loops

How can I loop the "Would you like to buy something else?" its at the bottom most of the code, after answering Yes then it will go back again from choosing from the available categories.

I'll place the switch again after knowing how can i loop this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char acoustic, electric, drums, piano, music, equip, Yes, No;

int pay1, pay2, pay3, pay4, pay5;
std::string answer;

int main()
{
cout << "Welcome to the Music Shop" << endl <<endl;

cout << "Categories                    Products                Price"<<endl;
cout << "[a] Acoustic Guitar      Fender Acoustic Guitar     P6,900.00"<< endl;
cout << "                         Hartwood Acoustic Guitar   P6,300.00" << endl;

cout << "[b] Electric Guitar      Gibson Electric Guitar     P8,500.00" << endl;
cout << "                         Ibanez Electric Guitar     P25,000.00" << endl;

cout << "[c] Drums                Pearl Drum Kits            P27,000.00" << endl;
cout << "                         Roland Electronic Drums    P24,000.00" << endl;

cout << "[d] Piano                Casio Digital Piano        P19,000.00" << endl;
cout << "                         Roland Piano               P120,000.00" << endl;

cout << "[e] Music Equipments     Guitar String              P113.00" << endl;
cout << "                         Headphones                 P1,600.00" << endl;
cout << "                         Amplifier                  P2,800.00" << endl;
cout << "                         Digital Mixer              P4,750.00" << endl;
cout << "                         Vocal Microphone           P860.00" << endl;
cout << "                         Guitar Tuner               P537.00" << endl;
cout << "                         Guitar Pick                P360.00" << endl<<endl;

cout << "Choose from the available categories: ";
cin >> music;

switch (music)
{
    case 'a':

    cout<< "Acoustic Guitar" << endl;
    cout<< "1. Fender Acoustic Guitar   - P6,900.00" << endl;
    cout<< "2. Hartwood Acoustic Guitar - P6,300.00" << endl <<endl;
    cout<<"Choose from the available Acoustic Guitars:";
    cin>>acoustic;

    if (acoustic == '1'){
        cout<<"Enter your payment:";
        cin>>pay1;
        if (pay1==6900){
            cout<<"You have succesfully purchased Fender Acoustic Guitar"<<endl;
        }
            else if (pay1>6900){
                pay1 -= 6900;
                cout<<"Your change is:"<<pay1<<endl;
            }
                else if (pay1<6900){
                    cout<<"You do not have enough money"<<endl;
                }
    }
    else if (acoustic == '2'){
        cout<<"Enter your payment:";
        cin>>pay1;
        if (pay1==6300){
            cout<<"You have succesfully purchased Fender Acoustic Guitar"<<endl;
        }
            else if (pay1>6300){
                pay1 -= 6300;
                cout<<"Your change is:"<<pay1<<endl;
            }
                else if (pay1<6300)
                {
                    cout<<"You do not have enough money"<<endl;
                }
    }
    else {
        cout<<"Invalid"<<endl;
    }

    break;

    case 'b':

    cout<< "Electric Guitar" << endl;
    cout<< "1. Gibson Electric Guitar   -P8,500.00" << endl;
    cout<< "2. Ibanez Electric Guitar   -P25,000.00" << endl <<endl;
    cout<<"Choose from the available Electric Guitars:";
    cin>>electric;

        if (electric=='1'){
        cout<<"Enter your payment:";
        cin>>pay2;
        if (pay2==8500){
            cout<<"You have succesfully purchased Fender Acoustic Guitar"<<endl;
        }
            else if (pay2>8500){
                pay2 -= 8500;
                cout<<"Your change is:"<<pay2<<endl;
            }
                else if(pay2<8500)
                {
                    cout<<"You do not have enough money"<<endl;
                }   
    }
    else if (electric=='2'){
        cout<<"Enter your payment:";
        cin>>pay2;
        if (pay2==25000)
        {
            cout<<"You have succesfully purchased Fender Acoustic Guitar"<<endl;
        }
            else if (pay2>25000){
                pay2 -= 25000;
                cout<<"Your change is:"<<pay2<<endl;
            }
                else if (pay2<25000)
                {
                    cout<<"You do not have enough money"<<endl;
                }   
    }
    else {
        cout<<"Invalid";
    } 
        break;

    case 'c':

    cout<< "Drums" << endl;
    cout<< "1. Pearl Drum Kits          -P27,000.00" << endl;
    cout<< "2. Roland Electronic Drums  -P24,000.00" << endl <<endl;
    cout<<"Choose from the available Drums:";
    cin>>drums;

        if (drums=='1'){
        cout<<"Enter your payment:";
        cin>>pay3;
        if (pay3==27000){
            cout<<"You have succesfully purchased Pearl Drum Kits"<<endl;
        }
            else if (pay3>27000){
                pay3 -= 27000;
                cout<<"Your change is:"<<pay3<<endl;
            }
                else if(pay3<27000)
                {
                    cout<<"You do not have enough money"<<endl;
                }   
    }
    else if (drums=='2'){
        cout<<"Enter your payment:";
        cin>>pay3;
        if (pay3==24000)
        {
            cout<<"You have succesfully purchased Rolans Electronic Drums"<<endl;
        }
            else if (pay3>24000){
                pay3 -= 24000;
                cout<<"Your change is:"<<pay3<<endl;
            }
                else if (pay3<25000)
                {
                    cout<<"You do not have enough money"<<endl;
                }   
    }
    else {
        cout<<"Invalid";
    }
     break;

     case 'd':

    cout<< "Piano" << endl;
    cout<< "1. Casio Digital Piano      -P19,000.00" << endl;
    cout<< "2. Roland Piano             -P120,000.00" << endl <<endl;
    cout<<"Choose from the available Piano:";
    cin>>piano;

        if (piano=='1'){
        cout<<"Enter your payment:";
        cin>>pay4;
        if (pay4==19000){
            cout<<"You have succesfully purchased Casio Digital Piano"<<endl;
        }
            else if (pay4>19000){
                pay4 -= 19000;
                cout<<"Your change is:"<<pay4<<endl;
            }
                else if(pay4<19000)
                {
                    cout<<"You do not have enough money"<<endl;
                }   
    }
    else if (piano=='2'){
        cout<<"Enter your payment:";
        cin>>pay4;
        if (pay4==120000){
            cout<<"You have succesfully purchased Roland Piano"<<endl;
        }
            else if (pay4>120000){
                pay4 -= 120000;
                cout<<"Your change is:"<<pay4<<endl;
            }
                else if(pay4<120000)
                {
                    cout<<"You do not have enough money"<<endl;
                }
    }
    else {
        cout<<"Invalid";
    }
     break;

     case 'e':

    cout<< "Music Equipments" << endl;
    cout << "1. Guitar String            -P113.00" << endl;
    cout << "2. Headphones               -P1,600.00" << endl;
    cout << "3. Amplifier                -P2,800.00" << endl;
    cout << "4. Digital Mixer            -P4,750.00" << endl;
    cout << "5. Vocal Microphone         -P860.00" << endl;
    cout << "6. Guitar Tuner             -P537.00" << endl;
    cout << "7. Guitar Pick              -P360.00" << endl <<endl;

    cout<<"Choose from the available Music Equipments:";
    cin>>equip;

        if (equip=='1'){
        cout<<"Enter your payment:";
        cin>>pay5;
        if (pay5==113){
            cout<<"You have succesfully purchased Guitar String"<<endl;
        }
            else if (pay5>113){
                pay5 -= 113;
                cout<<"Your change is:"<<pay5<<endl;
            }
                else if(pay5<113)
                {
                    cout<<"You do not have enough money"<<endl;
                }   
    }
    else if (equip=='2'){
        cout<<"Enter your payment:";
        cin>>pay5;
        if (pay5==1600){
            cout<<"You have succesfully purchased Headphones"<<endl;
        }
            else if (pay5>1600){
                pay5 -= 1600;
                cout<<"Your change is:"<<pay5<<endl;
            }
                else if(pay5<1600)
                {
                    cout<<"You do not have enough money"<<endl;
                }   
    }
    else if (equip=='2'){
        cout<<"Enter your payment:";
        cin>>pay5;
        if (pay5==1600){
            cout<<"You have succesfully purchased Headphones"<<endl;
        }
            else if (pay5>1600){
                pay5 -= 1600;
                cout<<"Your change is:"<<pay5<<endl;
            }
                else if(pay5<1600)
                {
                    cout<<"You do not have enough money"<<endl;
                }   
    }
    else if (equip=='3'){
        cout<<"Enter your payment:";
        cin>>pay5;
        if (pay5==2800){
            cout<<"You have succesfully purchased Amplifier"<<endl;
        }
            else if (pay5>2800){
                pay5 -= 2800;
                cout<<"Your change is:"<<pay5<<endl;
            }
                else if(pay5<2800)
                {
                    cout<<"You do not have enough money"<<endl;
                }   
    }
    else if (equip=='4'){
        cout<<"Enter your payment:";
        cin>>pay5;
        if (pay5==4750){
            cout<<"You have succesfully purchased Digital Mixer"<<endl;
        }
            else if (pay5>4750){
                pay5 -= 4750;
                cout<<"Your change is:"<<pay5<<endl;
            }
                else if(pay5<4750)
                {
                    cout<<"You do not have enough money"<<endl;
                }   
    }
    else if (equip=='5'){
        cout<<"Enter your payment:";
        cin>>pay5;
        if (pay5==860){
            cout<<"You have succesfully purchased Vocal Microphone"<<endl;
        }
            else if (pay5>860){
                pay5 -= 860;
                cout<<"Your change is:"<<pay5<<endl;
            }
                else if(pay5<860)
                {
                    cout<<"You do not have enough money"<<endl;
                }   
    }
    else if (equip=='6'){
        cout<<"Enter your payment:";
        cin>>pay5;
        if (pay5==537){
            cout<<"You have succesfully purchased Guitar Tuner"<<endl;
        }
            else if (pay5>537){
                pay5 -= 537;
                cout<<"Your change is:"<<pay5<<endl;
            }
                else if(pay5<537)
                {
                    cout<<"You do not have enough money"<<endl;
                }   
    }
    else if (equip=='7'){
        cout<<"Enter your payment:";
        cin>>pay5;
        if (pay5==360){
            cout<<"You have succesfully purchased Guitar Pick"<<endl;
        }
            else if (pay5>360){
                pay5 -= 360;
                cout<<"Your change is:"<<pay5<<endl;
            }
                else if(pay5<360)
                {
                    cout<<"You do not have enough money"<<endl;
                }   
    }
    else {
        cout<<"Invalid";
    }
}

 cout<<"\nWould you like to buy something else?"<<endl;
 cout<<"Yes or No?"<<endl;
 cin>>answer;

 if (answer == "Yes"){
 cout<<"Choose from the available categories"<<endl;
 cout<<"[a] Acoustic Guitar"<<endl;
 cout<<"[b] Electric Guitar"<<endl;
 cout<<"[c] Drums"<<endl;
 cout<<"[d] Piano"<<endl;
 cout<<"[e] Music Equipments"<<endl; 
 cin >> music;

 switch(music){
 }
}
else if (answer == "No"){
        cout<<"Thank you for visiting our shop come again";
}
}
```

Need the loop so i can just keep buying everytime i choose Yes

Comment: You should absolutely look at what a [mre] is, you posted that much entirely irrelevant code... You might look at [ask] and the [tour] as well.

Comment: You really don't need >300 lines of code to ask how to write a `do { ... } while(keepBuying)` loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In any case, you *will* need a loop.

There are several options, and it is rather a matter of taste which one to chose...

```
bool isContinue = true;
while(isContinue)
{
    // ...
    std::string input;
    // get input, convert to upper case for case-insensitive comparison
    isContinue = input == "YES"; 
}
```

Almost the same, but skipping very first (unnecessary comparison):

```
bool isContinue = false; // initial value is irrelevant, will be overwritten anyway
do
{
    // ...
    isContinue = input == "YES"; 
}
while(isContinue);
```

or an seemingly endless loop:

```
for(;;)
{
    // ...
    if(input != "YES")
        break;
}
```

The last variant is especially useful if you need to decide right in the middle of the loop body if you need to stop:

```
for(;;)
{
    // some initial work
    if(doWeNeedToStop)
        break;
    // some work to be done if we did NOT stop
}
```

Yet interesting: where to place the loop? Well, around all the stuff you want to repeat, so:

```
int main()
{
    // stuff you want to do only once at programme start,
    // e. g. welcome message
    for(;;)
    {
        // stuff you want to repeat
    }
    // stuff you want to do only once before programme ends,
    // e. g. printing a good-bye message

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In a very awful, but very fast way, you can use a `label` and a `goto` statement; here's a [doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/goto).

If you want to be cleaner, you might implement a `do-while` loop that checks the answer; like this:

```
do {
    // do your stuff
} while (answer == "Yes");

std::cout << "Thank you for visiting our shop come again";
```

Comment: Please don't recomment `goto` *at all* (at very, very least, not as first option) for such purposes (classifying as 'awful' doesn't suffice). There *are* good use-cases for `goto` (e. g. exiting nested loops), but having it as a replacement for a normal loop doesn't belong to these...

Comment: Agreed. Having seen code written by someone who had only learnt how to use if and goto (and no tabulation), it should be the very last construct to be considered. I would happily see it demised and haven't used one for about 2 decades now. It's basically a shortcut to branching in assembler.

Comment: @bloody - well I won't laugh back at you, as everyone is entitled to their view. To be specific, I didn't say any assembly instruction was a shortcut. I said that using gotos (in a 3GL) is a shortcut to using an assembly construct that is no longer necessary.